# babel transform the es6 template string only in single quote not double quote

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, jshint

the code of my scripts obey the jshint style, which only allow the javascript string in single quote. but when I use babel to translate my ES6 template file, it generate the string with the double quote sometimes, how can I prohibit this?

e.g: the template generate a code like this: 
`throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");`
I wish to generate:
`throw new TypeError('Cannot call a class as a function');`

Comment: Don't run jshint on transpiled output.

Comment: @user663031 What if you're running a code mod on source?

Answer (score 2):

Babel-generator package accepts `quotes` option. It seems to be broken now: https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/3367 but, after this will be fixed, you can use babel-generator manually to generate code according your code style:

```
var core = require('babel-core');
var generate = require('babel-generator');

var ast = core.transformFileSync('test.js', {
    // here should be your babel configuration
    presets: ['es2015']
}).ast;
console.log(generate.default(ast, {quotes: 'double'}).code);
```

You can't do it using CLI, because it doesn't accept this option as argument.

P.S. Using jshint or other code style checker on generated code is not good. Generated code is not inteded to be read by people, only ES6 sources should be shown for developers and allowed to edit.